Does JOOQ support creating PostgreSQL index with varchar_pattern_ops option?
I want to upgrade my PostgreSQL DB schema using a migrator running in Java and I'm using JOOQ for generating Java files for my project. Currently, to upgrade my DB schema I must drop the old index and replace it with an explicit SQL query including varchar_pattern_ops aka
String sqlQuery = String.format("CREATE INDEX %s ON %s (%s varchar_pattern_ops);", indexName, tableName, columnName);
PreparedStatement createIndexStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
createIndexStatement.execute();

Is there a way to avoid this method and using JOOQ out-of-the-box classes?

jOOQ will never support all of the thousands of vendor specific storage clauses out of the box in its DSL API, but it's always relatively easy to use plain SQL templates as a workaround, so you certainly don't have to fall back to using JDBC:
ctx.execute("create index {0} on {1} ({2} varchar_pattern_ops)",
    name(indexName),
    name(tableName),
    name(columnName)
);

Or even:
ctx.createIndex(indexName)
   .on(table(name(tableName)), field("{0} varchar_pattern_ops", name(fieldName)))
   .execute();

Remember to never concatenate strings when running SQL to avoid SQL injection and syntax errors. My example makes use of quoted identifiers within plain SQL templates for that reason.
